# Moveable but Non-Copyable Exceptions

Tags: c++, exception, c++11

I am thinking about writing non-copyable exception classes. I find it interesting, because then I don't have to worry about exceptions that could be thrown during allocations within the copy-constructor. If the creation of the exception object succeeds, everything is fine and there should be no issues with `std::terminate`.

```
struct exception
{
    exception() = default;
    exception(const exception&) = delete;
    exception(exception&&) noexcept = default;
    ~exception() noexcept = default;
    auto operator=(const exception&) -> exception& = delete;
    auto operator=(exception&&) noexcept -> exception& = delete;
};

int main()
{
    try {
        try {
            throw exception{};
        } catch (...) {
            std::rethrow_exception(
                std::current_exception());
        }
    } catch (const exception& e) {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

GCC-4.7 and Clang-3.2 accept the above code. However, I am a bit surprised. As far as I know, there are several situations where exception objects might be copied, e.g. `std::current_exception()` and `std::rethrow_exception()`.

**Question:** Is the above code correct according to C++11, i.e. will it be accepted by all compilers conforming to C++11?

*Edited:* Added `std::rethrow_exception` and `std::current_exception` to the example. Both compilers accept this version. This should make it clear, that if the compiler doesn't require a copy-constructor when an exception is thrown, the compiler won't require one when these two functions are used.

Comment: How often have you had the problem that an exception object throws an exception and causes termination?

Comment: 15.1/5 reads: "When the thrown object is a class object, the copy/move constructor and the destructor shall be accessible, even if the copy/move operation is elided."

Comment: I just wonder if a deleted function is considered accessible (your function is public). 8.4.3 doesn't mention anything about this.

Comment: @KerrekSB: I am not aware that a throwing copy constructor of an exception class has ever terminated one of my programs. However, I have written some services in the past, that had to work with out-of-memory situations. There are some guidelines recommending to not throw exceptions from an exception's class copy constructor, e.g. https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/cplusplus/ERR14-CPP.+Do+not+allow+an+exception+class%27s+copy+constructor+to+throw+exceptions

Answer (score 2):

`current_exception` says it refers either to the current exception or to a copy of it it, but doesn't say which. This suggests to me that:

- it is unspecified whether it is or not it's copied[*]
- therefore, your exception class is not good (certainly not if anyone might call `current_exception` on it)
- also therefore, it's no great surprise that it works in some implementations. There probably wouldn't be provision for the current exception *not* to be copied unless there was either demand for that from implementers or hope that implementers would avoid copies.

Just throwing the thing and catching it by reference is fine. The temporary in the `throw` expression is "used to initialize" the object used by the implementation to keep the current exception, so it can be moved or copied (according to which the class supports), and that move/copy can be elided.

For what it's worth, `make_exception_ptr` is specified to *always* copy. You could perhaps argue that this is a defect: `e` can be a by-value parameter in which case moving might be better. But that's my impetuous and ignorant impression, I've never even seen these functions before now.

[*] It's explicitly unspecified whether or not `current_exception` "creates a new copy each time it's called", but I'm not wholly certain whether that is intended to imply that it's unspecified whether it creates a new copy the first time it's called.

Answer (score 2):

> However, I am a bit surprised. As far as I know, there are several situations where exception objects might be copied, e.g. `std::current_exception()` and `std::rethrow_exception()`.

But you don't call any of them. The standard is quite clear about how the exception object is initialized. From 15.1, p3:

> A throw-expression initializes a temporary object, called the exception object , the type of which is determined by removing any top-level cv-qualifier s from the static type of the operand of throw and adjusting the type from “array of T” or “function returning T” to “pointer to T” or “pointer to function returning T”, respectively. The temporary is an lvalue and is used to initialize the variable named in the matching handler (15.3). If the type of the exception object would be an incomplete type or a pointer to an incomplete type other than (possibly cv-qualified) void the program is ill-formed. Except for these restrictions and the restrictions on type matching mentioned in 15.3, the operand of throw is treated exactly as a function argument in a
>   call (5.2.2) or the operand of a return statement.

In short, it acts like returning a type by value: the return value/exception object is initialized by the expression you provide. Because the expression you use is a temporary, it will act like returning a temporary from a function and invoke the move constructor. Granted, odds are good that this will be elided, but that's the point that 15.1, p5 makes:

> When the thrown object is a class object, the copy/move constructor and the destructor shall be accessible, even if the copy/move operation is elided (12.8).

This is just as true for returning values: the return value is initialized by copy/move initialization, where appropriate. Thus, the appropriate constructors have to be accessible, even if they're elided.

You can't throw your exception class in a way that would require copy-construction of the exception object. So you can't throw an lvalue; you can only throw a prvalue or an xvalue.

Nowhere in the standard does it say that the system is allowed to *arbitrarily* copy the exception for no reason. A call to `std::current_exception` may copy it. A call to `std::rethrow_exception` will likely copy it.

But if you don't call things that explicitly copy your exception objects, C++ is *not allowed* to do so willy-nilly.

Comment: Sorry, I do not agree with you. `std::current_exception` uses `std::exception_ptr` - not any concrete exception classes. The only way for the compiler to copy the exception requires magic at the point where the exception is thrown.

Comment: @nosid: You're missing the point: whatever "magic" happens when the exception is thrown has no bearing on whether a copy constructor needs to be called. The standard does not say that the exception you throw will be copied, and thus it doesn't need a copy constructor. Only calls to `current_exception` and other similar functions force the use of a copy constructor.

Comment: I think you're missing the point: If you replace the main function with `void foobar() { return exception{}; }`, i.e. a function with external linkage, the compiler has no clue if `std::current_exception` is used for my non-copyable exception. The only way to copy the exception when `std::current_exception` is actually used, is to do some magic at the point where the exception is thrown. It doesn't mean that the exception is copied at the throw point. However, the compiler can store a pointer to a function that will do the copy.

Comment: I meant `void foobar() { throw exception{}; }`.

Comment: @nosid: Whatever magic is required to make `current_exception` work, it is *not allowed* to require *all* exception types to be copyable. The C++ standard does not require that thrown objects be copyable unless you *copy them*. Therefore, the magic that makes it all work must work like the magic that allows `std::vector` to use non-copyable `T`'s while still having `push_back` which does require `T` to be copyable. It must be based on the attempt to copy the exception object, not on throwing it.

Comment: @nosid: Or, to put it another way, the standard does not say that the exception type must be copyable, therefore it *doesn't have to be*.